# Are there any limitations on how we use layouts in android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, user-experience, design-guidelines

I've created a good looking layout for my app, but I've used **relative layouts inside linear layouts**  (According to my needs).

Is this ok? my team partner told me that this does not follow the android guidelines and this would make the app go down in the search.

So basically, Are there any  **limitations**  on how we should use the layouts and does Google monitor these codes when the app is in the play store.

Here is the code (Had to put it in after an edit)

```
           <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/bio2"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bio1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="Sagar Vakkala"
                                            android:textStyle="bold"
                                            android:textColor="#000"
                                            android:id="@+id/namebio"
                                            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                                            />
                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_below="@id/namebio"
                                            android:textStyle="normal"
                                            android:text="From Delhi to Chennai in a whiff :)"
                                            android:textColor="#000"
                                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                            />


                            </RelativeLayout>




                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there is no such limitations..

Comment: Nesting layouts is bad for performances. You may take advantage of the RelativeLayout `relativity` and get rid of the container.

Comment: I don’t think they rank apps based on layout static files, though they might rank over performance. Don’t worry. Over time you will learn how to optimise your layouts and get rid of useless ViewGroups.

Comment: your team partner is totally wrong :)

Comment: Still didn't get a definite answer :(

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no limitations on how many layouts you add-in nor are there any of limitations that you've to follow for building an Android App. However google does monitor your apps, put on PlayStore.

Comment: google recommend using layouts as flat as possible, i.e. less hierarchical, but only for performance considerations, to make the app slightly faster. you can have 100 levels of layouts if you want and feel the activity is running sufficiently fast. see https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use ConstraintLayout instead.

Take a look in the documentation : 
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: Thanks for introducing that layout to me, But if this type of layout is already present then why do people still opt for relative layout?

Comment: Because ConstraintLayout is  the newest Layout  in Android and people dont know about it.

Answer (score 0):

try to reduce nesting linear layouts inside another one or two level is fine  , if you trying to comeup with a bit complex UI its better to extend android ViewGroup class and create your own view